# Finding how many combinations you can make of 200 strings of 50 beads each, with 2 different colors

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem in a class that is not super math-y, so either I have misunderstood this problem or it requires a lot of outside learning. Either way, my apologies for any lack of clarity.

I am interpreting the problem to be equivalent to this: there are 5,000 beads of one color and 5,000 beads of another color. You have to make 200 unique strings of 50 beads each. These are strings not necklaces, so left/right symmetry count as the same string, but rotations count as different strings, or in other words with a 4-string: ooox=xooo and oxoo=ooxo but both are unique strings. Also, the order of the 200 strings don't matter, so if there were 100 one-colored 50 strings that forces the other 100 strings of 50 to be all one color, and that counts for only one combination.

How many combinations will there be in total? I did this manually for 6 beads half of each color into strings of 3 and 2 (found 5 and 2 combinations), and for 8 beads into strings of 4 and 2 (found 11 and 3 combinations), to try to find some patterns but couldn't figure a way to formalize it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I will glad to help you if you can visualize (give drawing) of the example